# How can I check if form input is not all number before submitting form and show message?

Tags: javascript

I have a form

```
  <form id="login_form" action="login.aspx" method="post" onSubmit="return  isNumeric();">
       <label for="nid"> Number:</label>
       <input type="hidden" name="Context" value="NonAdminLogin" />
       <input type="text" name="nid" id="numbers" maxlength="25" tabindex="1" />
       <input type="submit" class="button" value="Log In" tabindex="3" />
   </form>
```

and before i submit it I want to make sure that the input name="nid" does not contain ALL NUMBERS.

For example if it has '9909k' it good , but if it has '45645' then I would like to show 
a message  below form.

I have try this fuction

```
function isNumeric(){

var numexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
if(document.getElementById('numbers').value.match(numexp)){
return true;
}else{
alert("Entry must be a number");
elem.focus();
return false;
}
}
```

to validate if its a numer of not, but does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/9x6rz5Lu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fiddle works but you need to change the script from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>`.

and you've used an undeclared variable.

```
elem.focus();
```

As @imtheman has done in his fiddle below. change `elem.focus();` to.

```
document.getElementById('numbers').focus();
```

Comment: I think that should be `No wrap - in <head>`. (Although it is "wrapped in the head section")... you'd think the fiddle was just an example of the problem; not _the_ problem!

Comment: @w3d Yeah No wrap - in <head> .. confusing stuff.